# Different ENV variable for each deployment pipeline on Codeship

Tags: git, codeship

I have JS application that consumes REST API specified in `API_HOST` environment variable.

Application has two deployment pipelines configured on Codeship for each branch (`develop`, `master`). For each branch I would like to provide different REST endpoint URL stored in `API_HOST`. Currently I have `API_HOST` variable defined under `Environment` tab but it doesn't work as it's globally defined for all deployment pipelines. Exporting `API_HOST` variable within `Custom Script` doesn't work neither.

I want to provide different `API_HOST` environment variable for every single deployment pipeline. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you wanting to have API_HOST available post deployment, or during testing?

Comment: During tesing. More precisely before building `bundle.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

**Codeship** exposes `CI_BRANCH` environment variable (among others as described here [Environment Variables On Codeship](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/set-environment-variables/#default-environment-variables)) so I was able to export `API_HOST` variable manually depending on branch name in `Test -> Setup Commands` like this:

`if [ "$CI_BRANCH" = "develop" ]; then export API_HOST="..."; elif [ "$CI_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then export API_HOST="'...'"; else echo "Unrecognized branch name."; fi;`

Thanks Codeship support team!

Comment: You can export the environment variables in your deploy script and after that you can run the application specific deployment scripts. e.g in my case, after exporting the values i call the `npm build`.